# Nonlinear models which are hard to estimate

Tags: estimation, genetic-algorithms, nonlinear-regression, optimization

Genetic algorithms are avoided in econometry literature as often as possible, but still sometimes they are inevitable. The question is: **Which well known models are the most difficult to estimate using conventional algorithms?** (By Conventional algorithms I mean Gauss-Newton method, Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm, and so on)

**Motivation:** I want to test some heuristic methods, and I need some benchmark to be sure that this particular model is really hard to estimate.

Comment: I'd say any model that involves lots of sines/cosines or decaying exponentials would make for badly-behaved problems.

Answer (score 3):

The **[travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)** is surely an archetypal hard optimization problem. To quote Wikipedia, "it is used as a benchmark for many optimization methods".

Comment: I know many problems not related to econometry which are used as a benchmark, but I want to focus on applications of GA in economics, and I thought that estimation of econometry model is good start.

Comment: Surely the travelling salesman problem has huge application within economics. Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by an 'econometry model'.

Comment: Sorry it was late, of course I meant econometric model. Example: Y=b1*x1+b2*x2^b3+(b4/x3+b5*x4)^b6 , but I'm not sure if this is hard to estimate using non-linear regression and secondly whether it has any real-world application.